# What are the differences among different notions of harmonic maps?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, global-analysis

Given smooth (compact, if needed) Riemannian manifolds $M$ and $N$. There are at least 3 different notions of harmonic maps (shortly, HM):

1. weakly HM.
2. stationary HM.
3. minimizing HM.

It is well-known that a smooth weakly HM must be stationary.

Question 1: What are the difference among the 3 notions of harmonic maps?

Question 2: Given a weakly HM $u:M \rightarrow N$, if it is smooth, is it true that $u$ must be a (locally) minimizing HM? Why?

Comment: For question 1 there is a good discussion in Helein's [book](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511543036).

Comment: @ArcticChar Could you tell me the name of that book? Thank you.

Comment: It's linked in my comment. Click the word "book". (anyway it's called Harmonic Maps, Conservation Laws and Moving Frames)

Comment: @ArcticChar Thank you so much.